# Double query for password when waken up

Tags: suspend, password, lightdm, policykit

When I turn on my laptop from sleep, I have to input my password twice. 
Once there is a white rectangular window (reminds me of gnome) and then lighdm unlock screen.
When I dissable "Ask for password after sleep", I still get the white window.

System:
Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity

**//EDIT:**

Unlock screen asks twice **only if AC is not plugged in**.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. It asks for the password even if AC is plugged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found a solution.

Package `gnome-screensaver` had to be removed, as it was installed as dependency and caused above bug.

To remove it, simply type in terminal:

`sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me, but It needed to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue since yesterday after a bunch of updates, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with the AC plugged in.

Removing the package `gnome-screensaver` helped, but I had to reboot to make it work. Before the reboot, I didn't get the grey password popup any more after resuming from stand-by, but also not the regular unity login either, so I couldn't log back in at all (also couldn't go to shell via CTRL+ALT+F1).

After a hard (power off) reboot, everything seems to be working again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but this answer is already posted